# Utilizing pipes to copy a file to a different destination, returning garbage values

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I am using C in a linux-based environment that utilizes system calls, pipes, fork, etc.
I'm able to copy the file into a separate destination, but I there are sometimes garbage values *added* into the output file, and I am unable to understand what triggers the issue, and why it happens.

**Here is the code!**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>

//defining the buffer size
#define SIZE_OF_BUFFER 50

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int fpipe[2];
    pid_t child_id;

//buffer to read the input file
    char readBuffer[SIZE_OF_BUFFER];

//creating a pipe
    pipe(fpipe);

//checking for valid number of parameters entered
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("ERROR: Enter 2 parameters only.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//Source file received as argument 1
    int sourceFile = open(argv[1], 0);

//Destination file received as argument 2,if file does not exist it will create one

    int destinationFile = open(argv[2], O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, 0666);

//check if file is able to open or not
    if (sourceFile == -1 || destinationFile == -1) {
        printf("ERROR: Couldnt open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//fork the child
    child_id = fork();

    if (child_id == 0) {
// inside the child prcocess
        close(fpipe[1]);

        while (read(fpipe[0], readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer)) > 0) {
// Writing to the destination file from pipe
            write(destinationFile, readBuffer, strlen(readBuffer) - 1);
        }

        close(fpipe[0]);
        close(destinationFile);
    } else {
// inside the parent process
        close(fpipe[0]);

// code to read from a text file and store in pipe
        while (read(sourceFile, readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer)) > 0) {
            write(fpipe[1], readBuffer, sizeof(readBuffer));
            memset(readBuffer, 0, SIZE_OF_BUFFER);
        }

        close(fpipe[1]);
        close(sourceFile);
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

**How to run:**
Compile in terminal, and run with

```
./a.out inputfile.txt outputfile.txt
```

where `inputfile` is a file you created that you would like to see copied over into the outputfile.
Total of 3 arguments.

Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: The parent is always writing `sizeof(readBuffer)`, even if you read less than that.  Check the number of bytes read and only write that many.

Comment: `strlen` is not a good way to do this.  When do null terminators get written?  (never).  Check the value returned by read rather than assuming the data is a properly null-terminated string.  (Are you assuming the data does not contain any null bytes?)

Comment: Go through you code, look at all places where you have used strlen(), or other such library calls that require a NUL-terminated char array, and ensure that condition is always met.  Then go through again, and ensure that the returns from system calls like read() are completely and correctly handled.